# React - Output an SVG Component Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-component

Im importing an SVG file as a ReactComponent.
I then want to output this component dynamically based on data from a request.

i.e.

```
import { ReactComponent as S1 } from '../../assets/images/characteristics/S1.svg';

 {characteristics.map(characteristic => (
   <div className="characteristic" key={characteristic.key}>
               <characteristic.key />
   </div>
}
```

where characteristic.key holds the name of the SVG i.e. "S1" in my example

How can i output the component as this does not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it like this instead:

```
import { ReactComponent as S1 } from "./path1.svg";
import { ReactComponent as S2 } from "./path2.svg";

// ...

function App() {
  // defining characteristics for demonstration purposes
  const characteristics = [
    { component: S1, key: "S1" },
    { component: S2, key: "S2" }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {characteristics.map(characteristic => (
        <div className="characteristic" key={characteristic.key}>
          <characteristic.component />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

So the string `"S1"` would be a good value for a key and you use `S1` from the import to actually render the svg component.